# Passing second column combobox selection to query in Access Forms

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2007

I have one table SUBACCOUNT_DETAIL that holds SUBACCT, and BUSINESS_MODEL_SW. BUSINESS_MODEL_SW is either Y or N (it would look like 91509 | Y, or 91510 | N).In table FUNDING_TYPE I have SUBACCT and FUNDING_TYPE_ID. I am making a combobox for SUBACCT in the FUNDING_TYPE table to bring up two columns, a subaccount and either Y or N depending on whether there is or is not a business switch. If the business switch for that subaccount is Y, then the FUNDING_TYPE_ID in the FUNDING_TYPE table can only be IDLL or TLL. If the business switch for that subaccount is N, then the FUNDING_TYPE_ID in the FUNDING_TYPE table can only be IDSC or TCS. I would like for the user to select the subaccount from the combobox, and have it generate the FUNDING_TYPE_ID combobox with either only IDLL & TLL (if business switch is Y), or IDSC (if business switch is N). I do not know how to reference the second column (Y or N) from the combobox to drive that next combobox. Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

You could design a query (update query) or you could make FUNDING_TYPE_ID field a calculated field

Try these approaches and if you have further questions, feel free to post them